# Project shows different output on Remote Server and local terminal for an IntelliJ Java Project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

If I run the Java project I coded in my IntelliJ IDE on my local terminal, I am able to get the output I want, but if I run the same project on a remote server terminal, the output is different. What can be the cause for this, or what should I be looking into? I have debugged in the IDE but code seems fine and gives correct output in local terminal. I copied and uploaded the whole project folder from IntelliJ to remote server.

Comment: Any code you can show us?

Comment: Did you copy a jar or the classes?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.